# When finishing a basement, how do I transition from walls to doors/windows?

Tags: insulation, basement, doors, windows, basement-refinishing

I am planning to finish my basement, which is currently naked poured concrete foundation throughout. I have a new door and new windows (only one shown in the Figure below because they are identical).

I am currently planning how to frame and insulate everything. Regarding framing, I will use 16" spaced 25 gauge steel studs. The house is located in Zone 5, and my insulation strategy is currently 1" XPS (R-5) and 3.5" Kraft-faced Fiberglass batting (R-15).

What's currently unclear to me is how to transition from this system to the door and window openings. Drawing and photo below for illustration.

- The door frame potrudes about 1" beyond the concete foundation, i.e. it will be flush with the XPS.
- The window is made of a steel frame (?) which is part of the foundation with the replacement windows sitting further towards the outside (this is not properly detailed out in the drawing, consult picture instead, please).

I would appreciate any help on how to transition from the insulated wall to the openings! Pointers to drawings of similar situations, descriptions, photos, whatever fits the situation... thank you!

[image: Drawing]

[image: The door]

[image: Side view of the door]

[image: The window]

[image: Side view of the window]

Comment: at a glance, it looks like the replacement window could be set 1/2" higher. This give you more to work with on the bottom edge. The world is your oyster. You can buy 1/4"x1/4" vinyl-foam modling, or any other 1/4" style you like (for example), and staple it in place. Just build a thin box around it to get some meat to bite into. (using 1/4" greenboard for example), giving you ~1/2" to build as a base.

Comment: Thank you @noybman! Yes, I with they placed the window a little bit higher, but I'm not motivated to move it again. Your comments gave me some ideas on how to fabricate a good box.